# rmarkdown Multiple Pages

Tags: shiny, r-markdown, shiny-server

I tried the following code to try displaying multi page
source: http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_shiny_advanced.html

for index.Rmd

````
```{r, echo = FALSE}

library(shiny)

selectInput("dataset", "Choose Dataset:", c("cars", "iris", "mtcars"))

renderTable({

head(mtcars, 5)

})

```

[Another Shiny Document](index2.Rmd)
````

for index2.Rmd

````
```{r, echo = FALSE}
library(shiny)
selectInput("dataset2", "Choose Dataset:", c("cars", "iris", "mtcars"))

activeDataset2 <- reactive({
get(input$dataset2, pos="package:datasets", inherits=FALSE)
})

renderPlot({
plot(activeDataset2())
})
```
````

it seems that shiny server will be able to display only index2.Rmd properly, where is the problem? Thanks for the help!

## update

The index.Rmd had an issue and now two files run as expected.

Comment: The select input only refers to a string (e.g., iris). If you have the name of an R-object you still need to 'get' it before you can use it.

Comment: Thanks, I realized there are was an issue in my original code